# Jupyter notebook xgboost import

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, xgboost

I have the problem below (I'm on a MAC)

I can import xgboost from python2.7 or python3.6 with my Terminal but the thing is that I can not import it on my Jupyter notebook.

```
import xgboost as xgb
```

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 import xgboost as xgb

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xgboost'

Although I write :

```
!pip3 install xgboost
```

It prints that :

Requirement already satisfied: xgboost in     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost-0.6-py3.6.egg
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from xgboost)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from xgboost)

Help please I searched everywhere :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Running a shell escape `!pip3` doesn't guarantee that it will install in the kernel you are running. Try:

```
import sys
print(sys.base_prefix)
```

and see if this matches either of your terminal pythons. You should be able to run `<base_prefix>/bin/pip install <package>` to ensure it is in the right `site-packages`.

You can also look at which `python` your kernel is running by looking in `kernel.json` most likely in `~/Library/Jupyter/kernels/<kernel>/kernel.json`.

Note: you can also programmatically install packages with:

```
import pip
pip.main(['install', '<package>'])
```

which will force it to be in the right `site-packages` for your kernel.

Answer (score 16):

Within Jupyter Notebook cell, try running:

`import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install xgboost`

This allows the package to be install with right on Jupiter notebook

Comment: Really helpful!

Comment: For more details on why this is preferable when using pip with jupyter notebook, check out [this](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/#How-to-use-Pip-from-the-Jupyter-Notebook) blog post.

Comment: this is THE solution!

Answer (score 2):

if you are using anaconda, you can install XGBoost with a command that mentioned below :

`conda install -c conda-forge xgboost`

Answer (score -2):

Since you are using macOS, you can use `Homebrew` to install `xgboost`:

In your terminal, run the following command:

```
brew install xgboost
```

See [this](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/xgboost) for details.