# xgboost Installation Visual studio code

Tags: python, installation, xgboost

I used the following code to install xgboost in terminal of Visual Studio Code:

```
py -3 -m venv .venv
.venv\scripts\activate

python -m pip install xgboost
```

I received this output:

```
> Requirement already satisfied: xgboost in
> c:\users\xxx\.venv\lib\site-packages (0.90) Requirement already
> satisfied: numpy in c:\users\xxx\.venv\lib\site-packages (from
> xgboost) (1.17.3) Requirement already satisfied: scipy in
> c:\users\xxx\.venv\lib\site-packages (from xgboost) (1.3.1)
```

but when I want to use xgboost in JupyterNotbook with `import xgboost as xgb`, I receive this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xgboost'

I am using Visual Studio Code in Windows.

Comment: How are you opening your jupyter notebook? Have you checked if your notebook is in the correct environment that you setup?

Comment: This is what I did: openfile>selectfile>tutorial.ipynb

Comment: So did you check if you are in your venv first before doing that?

Comment: Yes, I can load other packages like numpy and Re

Comment: You can try this solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44856105/jupyter-notebook-xgboost-import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44856105/jupyter-notebook-xgboost-import)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @ycx
this problem will be solved with this command:

```
!pip install xgboost
```